# How to execute a function after setInterval is completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a countdown timer. When this page is rendered the setInterval in useEffect exceutes and updates time. Now I want that after time is 0 it should log "Time finished".How to do that?

```
const startinMinutes = 1
  const startinHours = 0
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(startinHours)
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(startinMinutes)
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)

  const [time, setTime] = useState(hours * 60 * 60 + startinMinutes * 60)
  const update = () => {
    setTime(time - 1)
    setHours(Math.floor(time / 3600))
    let leftSeconds = time - 3600 * hours
    setMinutes(Math.floor(leftSeconds / 60))
    setSeconds(time % 60)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (time > 0) {
        update()
      }
      clearInterval(interval)
    }, 1000)
  })
```

Comment: You just need to add the log code in the callback function, what's your problem with that?

Comment: your interval clears itself after the callback is run, but what keeps it going is that the callback code sets state which causes the rerender and `useEffect` is set to run on every rerender. It works kind of like flawed `setTimeout` - you're creating a new interval on each rerender. This isn't a good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the conditional rendering like below:

```
if (time === 0) return <div>Time finished</div>;
else return <div>{time}</div>;
```

Check this working solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-wilson-xj4ow?file=/src/App.js:765-846

Answer (score 0):

You use the following code through solve your query perfectly.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 30, 2020 15:27:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        // console.log("done");
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```